# extract yahoo finance balance sheet with python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, yahoo-finance

I am learning to use beautifulsoup and python to extract an html table. I tried using the following code to extract the balance sheet for Google. However, I can't seem to get all the rows scraped correctly.

I can't manage to omit rows that is just a spacer and I don't manage to extract rows of the Totals (eg. Total Asset).

Any advice? Advice on simplifying the code also valuable.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

def bs_extract(stock_ticker):
    url= 'https://finance.yahoo.com/q/bs?s='+str(stock_ticker)+'&annual'
    source_code = requests.get(url)
    plain_text=source_code.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text)

    c1= ""
    c2= ""
    c3= ""
    c4= ""
    c5= ""

    table = soup.find("table", { "class" : "yfnc_tabledata1" })
    # print (table)
    for row in table.findAll("tr"):
        cells = row.findAll("td")
        if len(cells)==5:
            c1=cells[0].find(text=True)
            c2=cells[1].find(text=True)
            c3=cells[2].find(text=True)
            c4=cells[3].find(text=True)
            c5=cells[4].find(text=True)
        elif len(cells)==6:
            c1=cells[1].find(text=True)
            c2=cells[2].find(text=True)
            c3=cells[3].find(text=True)
            c4=cells[4].find(text=True)
            c5=cells[5].find(text=True)
        elif len(cells)==1:
            c1=cells[0].find(text=True)
            c2=""
            c3=""
            c4=""
            c5=""
        else:
            pass
        print(c1,c2,c3,c4,c5)

 bs_extract('goog')
```

Comment: The webpage for `goog` doesnt have a table with the class `yfnc_tabledata1` in it

Comment: Google and Yahoo are going to be displaying their tables very differently. `yfnc` is probably short for "Yahoo Finance". Why would Google be using their IDs and tags? Open up the Developer Tools for your browser and try to inspect elements for how to parse on the page you want.

Comment: A note on making this more Pythonic: You can fit those variables (c1, c2, etc.) in a list instead of separate variables, and then you don't have to have so much duplicate code.

Answer (score 0):

You might find it easier to get this data structured, through YQL. See http://goo.gl/qKeWXw

Comment: Just to respond to Kupiakos. I tried using bs_extract('msft') and you will find yfnc somewhere in the source. Good point on the list. Any idea why I can't extract the rows in bold (i.e. the Totals)?